# entity class from database wizard hangs

Tags: sql, database, netbeans, entity, persistence.xml

I'm developing a web app using Netbeans 7.3, Glassfish server and SQL Server 2008 (Schema named dbo and is 65 gigabytes).  I've connected to the database (in the "Services" tab) and now I am trying to create a `persistence.xml` using the wizard.

**Steps:** New File > Persistence >Entity Classes from Database > jdbc/AppName - and then, the "Retrieving the keys for xyz" progress bar appears and starts to run.  However, it gets halfway and then hangs.

I've been unable to find anything on why this is happening.  Is it due to a size limit - built into the wizard? Or, maybe an error in the database itself?

Any input would be great, thanks.